# Steps to use npm package (react-transition-group) under bsd-3-clause

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, bsd

I'd like to use the "React Transition Group" package from npm which is under [the bsd-3-clause license](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/master/LICENSE). If I read correctly I am free to use it in my web-app, but I don't understand if I have to write something in my LICENSE file.

In the BSD text it says:

- Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this
  list of conditions and the following disclaimer. **What does "retain" mean here? Do I have to license my product under BSD as well?**
- Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
  this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
  and/or other materials provided with the distribution. **I am developing a web-app, where would I have to put this, or would I even have to put it somewhere?**
- Neither the name of the copyright holder nor the names of its
  contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from
  this software without specific prior written permission.

I am looking for a clear directive on whether I can use this package and if I would have to change my license file or do something else. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redistribution of source code means the part of software, (here react-transition-group) should keep the bsd-license as it is. You are don't allowed to remove it from their code. It doesn't mean you have to use bsd-license for your whole app now.

As a website isn't binary data, second part don't match here.

I would say, be fair and give some honor to the developers, so that you describe which third-party-code you use, which licence those code have, and who was the creator of it.
Add it to a "credits / Licenses similar page" and all will be fine.